Hi guys, I went to open my project in Delphi today and I came across this error, several numbers 0 appear on the screen, what is this?,how can i fix?
I went to open my project in Delphi today and I came across this error, several numbers 0 appear on the screen, yesterday everthing was perfect, i saved the project, but today this fatal error

i tried to reboot my computer, open again the project but the same problem

I'm unable to see images on Stack Overflow. Hence, I'd appreciate a textual description of the image. In fact, one should always provide such a description because some people are blind. For example, "A screenshot of a modal message box with caption 'Frog Simulator' and text 'Are you sure you want to exit Frog Simulator?' There are three buttons: Yes, No, and Cancel. The dialog box also has a close title bar button."

@AndreasRejbrand You can always open the image in new window or new tab (right click on image and chose open in new tab). Besides in this case I think image might be worth a lot more.

@SilverWarior: No, I'm unable to see images on Stack Overflow. If I open the URL in a new tab, I only get a picture of a black cat and some text about "ray IDs". In any case, please note that I'm not suggesting using text instead of images, but in addition to images. Please use images, but also provide ALT texts.

Based on the image it is possible that your *.dproj file might be corrupted. Try opening your project from *.dpr file.

@AndreasRejbrand Then you have blocked access to the site that image has been posted on.

@SilverWarior: I certainly haven't. But maybe my ISP.

Sorry @AndreasRejbrand I couldn't think of a good description for this image, but I'll try to make you understand the error, on the screen is the delphi window in the code tab, the content of this tab is: 1000 times the number 0, and 2 errors messages:  [dcc32 Error]: E2029 Declaration expected but number found     and  [dcc32 Error]: E2029 '.' expected but end of file found. the design tab is unable

Thank you @SilverWarrion, i tried now, but the same error in dpr file, i'll import the units in a new project

What is the contents of your *.dpr file if you open it with a text viewer like Notepad for instance? If it contains only zeroes like in your image then something might have fully overwritten your *.dpr file.  Also you might want to perform a general file system check on your computer in case if the cause might be result of a faulty drive.

Now I'm at home and able to see the image. Yes, this is indeed very strange. Your IDE has the Code Editor showing the program file (*.dpr), and the IDE has opened this in binary mode and shows only null bytes. And the compiler says, "*.dpr: E2029: Declaration expected but number found". Would it really say so in a file with only NULL bytes? It seems like it takes the text from the editor instead (so the bytes are 30303030...). Likely that's because the file is "Modified", as seen in the status bar. If you open the *.dpr file in a hex editor, you can check if it is a text file or a ...

(cont.) binary file filled with NULL bytes. You can also try to open it in a text editor; then you would not expect to see zeros, but rather nothing at all. If your *.dpr file is indeed filled with NULL bytes, then it has been corrupted or overwritten. The *.dpr file should be the program's main file, a text file starting with program MyApp; uses .... If so, this is not really a Delphi issue, but some file management issue on your computer. There's also a non-zero chance that the IDE has corrupted your file, or fails to open it properly. Check the file in a hex or text editor to find out.

I opened the file in a text editor and the content is empty, opening it in a hexadecimal editor the file is filled with NULL bytes, the same 00000 appear, so the file was corrupted by a problem with my disk drive or file manager?

@GabrielRezendeCodogno: Or some other application on your computer. Hopefully, you have been doing regular backups, so you can restore the file from there.

yes, I can recover most of the progress, thank you all very much for your help, I wish you a great day

@SilverWarior: Many corporate proxies and ISPs block images. I worked for a corporation that did so, and never saw a single image from SO on my office computer for more than a decade. There are also many reasons to NOT use images, as described in Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Images should be used only as a last resort, when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, such as a rendering problem.

Looks like the .dfm file of the curenty open form in the project is severely damaged. It's a plain text file, can you [edit] its contents into the question?

@JanDoggen: It looks like the .dpr file contains NUL bytes.
